# Parse JSON string to detect error response

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-xe

i'm working with a server which response  using the JSON format.

when the request contain valid data they respond with a string like this

> {"data":{"results":[{"Branch":"ACCT590006"}]}}

but if the parameters of the request are incorrect the response goes like this

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"Invalid
>   Params"}],"code":98865,"message":"Invalid
>   param value"}}

So the questions are how i can determine when the response of the server contains a error string using the [`TJSONObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBXJSON.TJSONObject)   object and additionally parse the JSON string to show the messages and error codes like this.

```
Failed reason : invalid 
Message : Invalid params 
Code: 98865 
message : invalid param value.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked a little with JSON, an every time I've parsed from code(delphi 7). But i've searched a little bit, and here you may find the answer of your question:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/print/40882

and with a little adaption this should work.

Best regards,
Radu

Comment: I'll only add http://www.json.org/ as a main source of information related to JSON. If I have time, I'll make a small sample application to illustrate how to work with a standard JSON content.